# Delete iMessage chat history from work MacBook

Tags: messages

How do I delete all the iMessage chat history and logs from my work MacBook but still have them on my iPhone (they are synced).

The Mac is running macOS Mojave 10.14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply disable the iMessage account on your Mac.

Open Messages app preferences (by using keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>), go to iMessage tab. Under Settings just below your Apple ID, uncheck **Enable this account**.

[image]

Comment: Does that effect existing ones that are potentially stored?

Comment: @UIO Please clarify.

Comment: Apologies, Are any logs stored on the mac, if so will clicking that option remove them all or just stop storing them from the point that it is selected?

Comment: @UIO, All iMessages associated with the Apple ID are removed from local storage. You'll need to login again to use iMessage. You will be able to restore them on Mac if you have enabled Messages in iCloud.

Comment: One quick thing, if i do that then open iMessage again and then skip the sign in by pressing the "not now" buttin it brings my messages up again as if im signed in, how do i delete this?

Comment: @UIO Delete those messages manually.